# Angular communicating between components

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have 2 components. CategoryComponent and CategoryProductComponent. And I also have a service CartegoryService. CategoryComponent returns a table with a list of categories which I fetch from my CategoryService. On each row of the table has a button that when clicked takes you from the CategoryComponent to CategoryProductComponent which shows you the list of products in that category.

From my Api when I get the json, I have links array that has rel = category-product and has an href with the full link to fetch the related products.

Now the problem is when I fetch the json in the CategoryComponent and when a user clicks the link to see the list of products , i get that link and then call method in the CategoryService and then assign it to a variable after that I call the route.navigate to the CategoryProductComponent which now fetches the productlist since the link was assigned.

This doesnt work when I put in the url manually in the browser, cos then the link is not fectched from the CategoryComponent.  I read that services are singletons so I was thinking the variable will stay populated at least after the first time it is assigned. 
What best way can I do this communication between my components.

Also I can pass the link as an extra object in the router.navigate but i dont see this to be ideal especially when one decides to type in the url directly in the browser.

category.component.ts

```
    import { Category, FinalCategoryResponse, CategoryResponse, Link } from './category';
import { CategoryService } from './category.service';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category',
  templateUrl: './category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category.component.css']
})
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  categories: Category[];
  categoryResponses: CategoryResponse[];
  constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categoryService.getCategories()
      .subscribe(responseCategories => this.categoryResponses = responseCategories
         ,  (err) => {
      if (err.error instanceof Error) {
        // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
        console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
      } else {
        // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
        // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
        console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
      }
    });
  }

  showCategoryProducts(categoryResponse: CategoryResponse , relName: string) {
     const links: Link[] = categoryResponse.links;
      for (const link of links) {
        if (link.rel === relName) {
            this.categoryService.assignCategoryProductLink(link.href);
            this.router.navigate(['/categories', categoryResponse.category.id, 'products']);
        }
      }
  }


    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // unsubscribe to all subscriptions here
      }
}
```

category-service.ts

```
       import { Product } from '../product/product';
import { Category, FinalCategoryResponse, CategoryResponse } from './category';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {

  private categoryProductLink: string;
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getCategories() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/categories')
      .map(response => <CategoryResponse[]>response.json());
  }

  assignCategoryProductLink(link: string) {
    this.categoryProductLink = link;
  }

  getCategoryProducts() {
    return this.http.get(this.categoryProductLink)
        .map(response => <Product[]>response.json());
  }
}
```

category-product.component.ts

```
    import { Product } from '../../product/product';
import { CategoryService } from '../category.service';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category-product',
 templateUrl: './category.product-component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class CategoryProductComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  products: Product[];
  constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categoryService.getCategoryProducts()
    .subscribe(results => this.products = results);
  }


 ngOnDestroy(): void {

  }
}
```

category.module

```
    import { CategoryComponent } from './category.component';
import { CategoryService } from './category.service';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CategoryProductComponent } from './category-product/category-product.component';
import { CategoryRoutingModule } from './category-routing.module';
import { AddCategoryComponent } from './add-category/add-category.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CategoryRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
  CategoryComponent,
  CategoryProductComponent,
  AddCategoryComponent
  ],
  exports : [CategoryComponent, CategoryProductComponent, AddCategoryComponent],

  providers : [CategoryService]
})
export class CategoryModule { }
```

Thanks

Comment: You've posted your CategoryComponent twice instead of your CategoryService

Comment: Please also provide the parent module - which needs to declare both components and provide the service in order to share the same service instance between the components.

Comment: @Steveland83 i have corrected it

Comment: @Steveland83 i have provided the parent module as well. But there is not problem with that , it works just my approach is not right. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 2):

I didnt spot this when I first read your question.

> This doesnt work when I put in the url manually in the browser

Using the Angular router maintains your application state since you are not actually navigating anywhere when you use it, but *manually entering the link into your browser* means you're deep linking into your app - and I'm fairly sure it loses any state that it had previously, since you're effectively restarting the app.

Side note - I'm quite surprised that this is an issue for you, surely this is expected behaviour?

If you really want to provide for that requirement, then in CategoryService you can store the data with `localstorage` as follows:

```
  setCategoryProductLink(link: string) {
    localStorage.setItem('categoryProductLink', link);
  }

  getCategoryProductLink(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem('categoryProductLink');
  }
```

This will persist it between sessions.

Comment: I understand this is the expected behaviour , because it doesnt go to the CategoryComponent first which it doesnt have the link to get the products from the service.

Using the local storage means I will have to atleast once. And I cant directly go straight to the categoryproductLink page without going to the categorypage.
Also there are a list of products and every click will give a new link.

Another way I can do this is to just not use the related link but just get the id from the url browser and do my fetch accordingly. But then I dont get the chance to make use of my rel links.

Comment: All I am asking for is a way to use my rel links betweens components

Comment: Why dont you combine url + localstorage approaches. So in your service, first you check if there is a matching route parameter, and if there isnt then look in localstorage. I think that will handle both of your requirements, if I understand them correctly.

Comment: I would have opted to just use the route parameters , dont see how I can use the related links between components